# Does there exist a regular octahedron such that...

Tags: geometry

Does there exist a regular octahedron such that it is inscribed in the unit cube and octahedron's vertices belong to $\bf\Large{exactly\; 8}$ edges of the cube?

I think if it exist then octahedron's center can't coincide with cube's center.

Comment: octahedron has 6 vertices

Comment: @WillJagy Your comment made me rewrite my "clearly no" answer to a "clearly yes" :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I try to improve the world, one comment at a time. My biggest regret is that I am gradually losing the hair on the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:** If $C$ is a cube, there exists no inscribed regular octahedron whose vertices belong to exactly eight edges of $C$.

A point $p$ of the $1$-skeleton of $C$ lies on either three edges or one, depending whether $p$ is a vertex or not.

Let $O$ be an octahedron whose vertices lie on exactly eight edges of $C$. At least one vertex of $O$ must be a vertex of $C$, since $O$ has only six vertices.

**$O$ and $C$ cannot have two or more common vertices.**

**Proof** Assume from now on that $C$ is a *unit* cube. Note that a regular octahedron with unit-length edges has volume $\sqrt{2}/3$. Suppose two vertices $p_1$ and $p_2$ of $O$ are vertices of $C$.

If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are adjacent in $O$ and not adjacent in $C$, then the edges of $O$ have length at least $\sqrt{2}$, so the volume of $O$ exceeds the volume of $C$.

If instead $p_1$ and $p_2$ are adjacent in $C$ (so they lie in exactly five edges of $C$), then the remaining four vertices of $O$, which all lie within a cylinder of radius $1$ about the edge $p_1p_2$, do not touch the $1$-skeleton of $C$.

Finally, "antipodal" vertices $p_1$ and $p_2$ of $O$ cannot both be vertices of $C$; they would have to be antipodal in $C$ as well (since all other pairs of vertices lie in some face of $C$), and a unit cube does not contain three mutually-perpendicular axes of length $\sqrt{3}$ through its center. (There are precisely four segments of length $\sqrt{3}$ in a unit cube, and no two are orthogonal.)

It follows immediately that three or more vertices of $O$ cannot be vertices of $C$.

**$O$ and $C$ cannot have exactly one vertex in common.**

**Proof** If $O$ and $C$ have exactly one common vertex and the vertices of $O$ lie in exactly eight edges of $C$, then every vertex of $O$ lies on an edge of $C$. (The common vertex lies in three edges of $C$, and each of the remaining five vertices of $O$ must lie on an edge of $C$.)

If $p$ is a vertex of both $O$ and $C$, then the four vertices of $O$ adjacent to $p$, which are vertices of a square, lie in some sphere centered at $p$. But clearly no sphere centered at $p$ hits exactly four edges of $C$.

This exhausts all possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider a main diagonal.
Two planes at the same distance from the center, orthogonal to this diagonal cut off triangular pyramids if they are between $\frac16$ and $\frac12$ of the diagonal length away from the center. By continuity (intermediate value theorem), at some suitable distance the six points of intersection make up an octahedron.

Comment: Is it regular?  I believe the bases of the pyramids are equilateral, but what about the other six faces?

Comment: My opinion is that this is a perfectly good sketch of a proof.  See my answer below.

Comment: Though I upvoted Ross Millikan's comment, I'm now convinced it's possible to make the octahedron regular. (And while I was typing this, Jim Belk posted the vertices.) However, this octahedron seems not to have vertices belonging to exactly _eight_ edges of the cube.

Comment: @JimBelk, this is not an answer, because the main conncern is "8 edges"

Comment: @Norbert As others, I thought the 8 was a typo. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Let the cube be $[0,1]^3$.  Following Hagen von Eitzen's suggestion, the coordinates of the six points are:
$$
(3/4,0,0),\quad (0,3/4,0),\quad (0,0,3/4),\quad (1/4,1,1),\quad (1,1/4,1),\quad (1,1,1/4).
$$
Note that the distance from $(3/4,0,0)$ to $(0,3/4,0)$ is the same as the distance from $(3/4,0,0)$ to $(1,1/4,1)$.

Comment: even if this is a regular octehedron its vertices belong to 6 edges of the cube, not eight

Comment: @Norbert I just assumed the eight was a typo, and that you meant exactly six edges.  My mistake.